# Using ng-repeat, filter, and uib-popup-datepicker to filter table column results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a common scenario for an angular application I am working and have not been able to solve this pattern. I've searched thoroughly for an answer to this scenario, but all like questions do not seem to work in my app or resolve the issue of excluding time when html5 input type date element and ng-repeat.

I need to filter items from ng-repeat using an html5 input of type 'date' (alternatively using Angular-UI-Bootstrap's 'uib-popup-datepicker').

I am able to store the user's input in a javascript object with the following format (the name of 'date' property may change based on what the date represents as I have many different types of objects with multiple dates stored within):

input field ng-model

```
search.date
```

javascript object

```
object.date
```

I believe I am encountering my issue where the html5 input type date element returns is a JavaScript Date object in the following format:

```
"2016-11-17T08:00:00.000Z"
```

The JSON results I receive by consuming a HAL-compliant REST API for the date is in the following format:

```
2016-11-17T09:30:00.000+0000
```

I only want to filter on the Date, excluding the Time. I believe that ng-repeat is using the full date (including the time) where by removing any item that is not an exact match full Date/Time. This is not the behavior I desire. I hope to display all items that take place on the filter date.

Here is a screen shot of page after it has rendered, followed by it's HTML:
[image]
HTML (omitting the panel and up):

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <table id="outstandingBills" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <th class="form-group checkbox">
                <span>Select to Bill</span><br>
                <label style="margin-top: 8px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                           name="selectAll" 
                           value="true" 
                           ng-model="financeBillingCtrl.isAllSelected" 
                           ng-click="financeBillingCtrl.selectAll()" /> Select All
                </label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="filter_name">Customer Name</label>
                <input type="input" 
                       class="form-control" 
                       id="filter_customer_name" 
                       name="filter_customer_name" 
                       placeholder="Filter by Name"
                       ng-model="search.customer.name" />
            </th>
                <th>
                    <label for="filter_bill">Bill Amount</label>
                    <input type="input" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           id="filter_bill_amount" 
                           name="filter_bill_amount" 
                           placeholder="Filter by Bill Amount"
                           ng-model="search.billAmount" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label for="filter_total">Open Total</label>
                    <input type="input" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           id="filter_open_total" 
                           name="filter_open_total" 
                           placeholder="Filter by Total Billable Amount"
                           ng-model="search.openTotal"/>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label for="filter_date">Last Billed</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" 
                               class="form-control" 
                               uib-datepicker-popup 
                               ng-model="search.lastBillDate" 
                               ng-change="financeBillingCtrl.instanceType(search.lastBillDate)"
                               is-open="financeBillingCtrl.datepickerLastBilled.isOpen" 
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                               ng-required="false" 
                               close-text="Close" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button type="button" 
                                  class="btn btn-default" 
                                  ng-model="financeBillingCtrl.datepickerLastBilled.date"
                                  ng-click="financeBillingCtrl.toggleDatepicker(financeBillingCtrl.datepickerLastBilled)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="customerBillingItem in financeBillingCtrl.customerBillingItems | filter: search | filter: {lastBillDate: search.lastBillDate}">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="bill" 
                               value="true"
                               ng-model="customerBillingItem.selected" />
                    </td>
                    <!--<td><a href="{{ mainCtrl.baseUrl }}/system{{ mainCtrl.parseLink( customerBillingItem.customer._links.subscriptions.href ) }}">{{ customerBillingItem.customer.name }}</a></td>-->
                    <td><a href="{{ mainCtrl.baseUrl }}/system/customers/1/vendorBillingItems/1/subscriptions">{{ customerBillingItem.customer.name }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ customerBillingItem.billAmount | currency }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customerBillingItem.openTotal | currency }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customerBillingItem.lastBillDate | date }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        Paging Here
    </div>
</div>
<!-- RESULTS - END -->
<pre>
search.lastBillDate:
{{ search.lastBillDate }}

items.lastBillDate: 
<span ng-repeat="item in financeBillingCtrl.customerBillingItems">{{ item.lastBillDate }}<br></span>
</pre>
```

Here is a screenshot of the page after using the filter (I use

to display the current values of objects):
[image]

Controller Code:

```
/***************************** DATE PICKER - START *****************************/

    // CONFIGURATION - Date Pickers
    // Datepicker - Filter: Start Date
    financeBillingCtrl.datepickerFilterStartDate = {
        isOpen : false,     // Default the lastBilled datepicker to closed
        date: new Date()    // Used with ng-model to set the Default Date Selection
    };
    // Datepicker - Filter: End Date
    financeBillingCtrl.datepickerFilterEndDate = {
        isOpen : false,     // Default the lastBilled datepicker to closed
        date: new Date()    // Used with ng-model to set the Default Date Selection
    };
    // Datepicker - Table Column Filter: Last Billed
    financeBillingCtrl.datepickerLastBilled = {
        isOpen : false      // Default the lastBilled datepicker to closed
    };

    // Events - Date Pickers
    financeBillingCtrl.toggleDatepicker = function(datepicker) {
        console.log(financeBillingCtrl.CLASSNAME + ".toggleDatepicker()");
        console.log("PRE__CHANGE - datepicker.isOpen: " + datepicker.isOpen);
        // Update the 'isOpen' variable on the supplied datepicker
        datepicker.isOpen = ! datepicker.isOpen;
        console.log("POST_CHANGE - datepicker.isOpen: " + datepicker.isOpen);
    };

    financeBillingCtrl.instanceType = function(instance) {
        console.log(financeBillingCtrl.CLASSNAME + ".instanceType(instance: " + instance + ")");
        var result = "";
        if (instance == null) {
            result += "Vanilla null, ";
        }
        if (instance == undefined) {
            result += "Vanilla undefined, ";
        }
        if (angular.isDefined(instance)) {
            result += "Defined, ";
        }
        if (angular.isUndefined(instance)) {
            result += "Undefined, ";
        }
        if (angular.isObject(instance)) {
            result += "Object, ";
        }
        if (angular.isDate(instance)) {
            result += "Date ";
        }
        if (angular.isNumber(instance)) {
            result += "Number ";
        }
        if (angular.isString(instance)) {
            result += "String ";
        }
        if (angular.isFunction(instance)) {
            result += "Function ";
        }

        console.log("$scope: ", $scope);
        console.log("instanceType: " + result);
        return result;
    };

    // ON INIT - Date Pickers


/***************************** DATE PICKER - END   *****************************/
```

Comment: You'll need to create custom filter (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) that will take each item in the ng-repeat, parse/compare date without time as needed, and return a collection of valid elements. You'd be returning a function that takes input as well as optional params such as the search ng-model you are checking on. You'd also be able to combine the two filters to get exactly the results you are looking for. `app.filter('someCustomFilter', function () { return function(input, char) { return someCollectionVariable; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two options:

1) Convert all dates to a consistent format. When you consume the REST API, convert it into UTC format so that it is the same as the native datepicker.

2) Perform filtering in the controller (this is much faster and is the recommended approach).

So, you could for example have two arrays:

```
var originalBillingItems = []
var filteredBillingItems = []
```

Then in the uib-datepicker-popup you can bind a function to the ng-change attribute. So for example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    uib-datepicker-popup 
    ng-model="search.lastBillDate" 
    ng-change="financeBillingCtrl.filterByDate()">
```

and then in the controller you can have a function

```
ctrl.filterByDate = function () {
    filteredBillingItemsArray = angular.copy(originalBillingItems)
    //filter however you want here
}
```

then in the ng-repeat instead of using originalBillingItems you use filteredBillingItems.

This has the benefit of removing the filtering from the digest cycle which is very wasteful and is only recommended if the list is going to be very small.